# Create tree recursively in C and can't return from the CreateTree() function

Tags: c, data-structures

Like this question:[Create and traverse a binary tree recursively in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631367/create-and-traverse-a-binary-tree-recursively-in-c). I use the pointer to pointer for create Tree struct.These code can be compiled but cann't return from the CreateTree() function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
typedef char ElemType;

// Tree struct
typedef struct tree
{
    ElemType data;
    struct tree * lchild;
    struct tree * rchild;
}TreeNode,* Tree;


void CreateTree(Tree* t)
{
    char ch;
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    if ( ch == '#' ){
        *t = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        *t = (Tree)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
        if ( !(*t) )
        {
            printf("memory allocate error！");
            return ;
        }
        (*t)->data = ch;
        CreateTree(&((*t)->lchild));
        CreateTree(&((*t)->rchild));
    }
    return ;
}

int main()
{
    Tree T = NULL;
    printf("\nPlease input node in preorder way，'#'means NULL：");
    CreateTree(&T);
}
```

Comment: `CreateTree(T);` that *doesn't* puke a big warning or error ??? That should be `CreateTree(&T);` and ideally `T` should be primed with `NULL` beforehand. And stop hiding pointer types in typedefs. It's a terrible habit and hides where pointers are vs aren't. There are only two reasons to do it, and you're doing *neither* in this code.

Comment: I mean CreateTree() function cannot finish

Answer (score 0):

reason that you code was not ending is : the char entered was not flush and it get used in further iteration.
just added getchar() and it works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
// Tree struct
typedef struct tree
{
    char data;
    struct tree * lchild;
    struct tree * rchild;
}TreeNode,* Tree;


void CreateTree(Tree* t)
{
    char ch;
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    if ( ch == '#' ){
        *t = NULL;
         **getchar();**
    }
    else
    {
        *t = (Tree)malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
        if ( !(*t) )
        {
            printf("memory allocate error！");
            return ;
        }
        (*t)->data = ch;
         **getchar();**
        CreateTree(&((*t)->lchild));
        CreateTree(&((*t)->rchild));
    }
    return ;
}

int main()
{
    Tree T = NULL;
    printf("\nPlease input node in preorder way，'#'means NULL：");
    CreateTree(&T);
}
```